# How to retrieve nested JSON objects in React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am still learning React-Redux. I understand how to retrieve simple JSON arrays/objects. However, I am not sure how to call a nested object. When this is bundled, I am viewing the 'after' object - t3_5t61fz - obviously because I'm calling data.after, but when I try to implement data.title nothing appears. I am trying to grab the title and am viewing this in the console:

- Object

  - data : Object

    - data : Object

      - data : Object

        - after : "t3_5t61fz" before : null children : Array[25]

          - 0 : Object

            - data : Object

              - title : "How Google builds a web framework"

Reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state={
    data: {
      data: {}
    },
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
  }, action) {

    switch(action.type){
      case "FETCH_DATA":{
        return {...state, fetching:true}
      }
      case "FETCH_DATA_REJECTED":{
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
      }
      case "FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED":{
        return {...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, data: action.payload}
      }
      case "ADD_DATA":{
        return {...state, data: [...state.data, action.payload]}
      }
      case "UPDATE_DATA":{
        const { id, title } = action.payload
        const newData = [...state.data]
        const dataToUpdate = newData.findIndex(data => data.id === id)
        newData[dataToUpdate] = action.payload;

        return {...state, data: newData}
      }
      case "DELETE_DATA":{
        return {...state, data: state.data.filter(data => data.id !== action.payload)}
      }
    }
    return state
  }
```

Action

```
import axios from 'axios';


export function fetchData(){
  return function(dispatch){
    axios.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/top/.json")
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_REJECTED", payload: err})
    })
  }
}

export function addData(id, text){
  return {
    type: 'ADD_DATA',
    payload:{
      id,
      data,
    },
  }
}

export function updateData(id, text){
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_DATA',
    payload: {
      id,
      data,
    },
  }
}

export function deleteData(id){
  return {
    type: 'DELETE_DATA',
    payload: id
  }
}
```

Layout.js

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import { fetchData } from "../actions/dataActions"

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    data: store.data.data
  };
})
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData())
  }


  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;


    return <div>
      <h1>{data.data.after}</h1>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm calling data.after, but when I try to implement data.title nothing appears

I see that `data.after` is an array, and you are trying to get the title of the data of the first item in that array.

You should be able to access the data in your `<h1>` by getting `{data.data.after[0].data.title}`

Im curious why the data is being so deeply nested in this fashion though.

Comment: I'm getting this error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' :(